# Minimal $k$-colouring of the line graph of $K_n$, $L(K_n)$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm trying to find $\chi(L(K_{10}))$ which is the minimal coloring of the vertices of $L(K_n)$.
By *Vizing*, we know that $\Delta(K_n)\leq \chi(L(K_n))\leq \Delta(K_n)+1$ and this yields the inequality $$ 9\leq \chi(L(K_{10})) \leq 10$$
How do I proceed from here on? Test a 9-colouring and see if it is proper?

Comment: @saulspatz Vizing's theorem relates the maximum degree of $G$ (not of $L(G)$) to the chromatic index $\chi'(G)$, which is exactly the chromatic number of $L(G)$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks.  I somehow misread the $\chi$ as $\chi'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All considered graphs are finite, simple and undirected.

Consider such a graph $G$. We first observe that the chromatic index $\chi'(G)$ is equal to the chromatic number of its line graph $L(G)$.

The following is due to results of Behzad et. al in "The colour numbers of complete graphs. Journal of the London Mathematical Society 1.1 (1967): 226-228."

Let $K_n$ be a complete graph on $n$ vertices, then

$$
 \chi'(K_n)= \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
n \text{ for odd } n \geq 3\\
n-1 \text{ for } n \text{ even} 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

The proof can be found in the above paper.

Hence, $\chi(L(K_{10}))=\chi'(K_{10}) =9$.

Using SageMath to confirm:

```
G = graphs.CompleteGraph(10)
h = G.line_graph()
print(h.chromatic_number())
```

Of course the above yields to $9$.

The above theorem is discussed in this network [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172005/chromatic-index-of-a-complete-graph).

Comment: Thank you I'll try and read it :)